# Unix environment variables with arguments

Tags: unix, zsh, environment-variables

I'm trying to set my $EDITOR variable to be emacs with no window, so the command to call it would be `emacs -nw`. However if I set it like this:

`export EDITOR="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"`

I get the following error

`zsh: no such file or directory: /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -n`

Comment: Have you checked if the programs take environment variables of configuration files to set such switches?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this doesn't work because the shell would try to open a binary with the space included in the file name, so `Emacs -nw`, and not open `Emacs` and then pass `-nw` as the options.

How about making `$EDITOR` a small (executable) script, e.g. in `~/bin/EDITOR`?

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw -- "$@"
```

Then, simply add to your shell's configuration:

```
export EDITOR=~/bin/EDITOR
```

Now, `EDITOR` will call the script with the appropriate arguments, expanded in `$@`.

Answer (score 8):

As explained here: [zsh: Command not found (for $EDITOR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299610/zsh-command-not-found-for-editor)
, zsh treats the expanded variable as a single word (that has space characters in it).

Possible solutions are:

- run in bash which expands the spaces properly
- Use the '=' modifier on parameter expansion: see [Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-SH_005fWORD_005fSPLIT_002c-toggle) in the `zsh` documentation and look for '${=spec}'
- use eval when calling $EDITOR as in:

  `eval $EDITOR file`